# Change file names before uploading with SWFUpload

Tags: javascript, swfupload

I am using SWFUpload to allow users to upload multiple files in any browser. A user can provide custom file names for the files being uploaded. How can I iterate through all the queued files and update the name of the file to the custom name before the file is uploaded.

If I can't change the file name, how do I add a post parameter to each file being uploaded to make the change on the server side? I know how to add parameters for all files but how would I do it for each file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update the actual name of the file that gets sent in the POST body of the file upload because internally, SWFUpload is using a FileReference which doesn't let you change any of the file's properties before uploading it (and there's no way to get proper upload progress without using a FileReference to do the uploading, so this isn't something that can really be changed).

However, you should be able to add an extra POST parameter per file via the [`addFileParam` function](http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/#addFileParam). Its signature is:

```
addFileParam(file_id:String, name:String, value:String):Boolean
```

Comment: So how do I iterate through the files to use the addFileParam to each file?

Comment: I added an uploadStart function that runs before each file upload and was able to use addFileParam(...) to get the proper information passed.