# How to read and write a file using SWFUpload in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, swfupload

I am using SWFUpload for uploading files from client to server. When I select a file to upload, before it uploads I want to read that file, write some additional data to it, then it should be appear for upload on server.

Is it possible? If it is then please provide me solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always use a server side script like PHP to add additional data to the uploaded file before saving it on disk on in a database.

Comment: What type of data are you looking to add.. your server side could easily add this data depending on what it is, before you process the image..

Comment: @Rabbott I am uploading a file that contain company information, hence before it upload on server I want to add company address at company address column, hence I need to read that file and then write into that file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to one on [changing file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291754/change-file-names-before-uploading-with-swfupload). Use a combination of [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cf8.html), [event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301839/flexs-filereference-save-can-only-be-called-in-a-user-event-handler-how-ca), [deserialization](http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/8.2/programLC/programmer/lcds/serialize_data_3.html), and [transformation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/filereference_class_as3.html).